# Spring Cloud Gateway: Only Routes from Last Imported YAML File are loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud

**Description:**

I'm currently working on a Spring Cloud Gateway project where I've organized my route configurations into separate YAML files for each microservice. However, I'm facing an issue where only the routes from the last imported YAML file are visible in /actuator/gateway/routes. Here's an overview of my project and the problem:

**Project Overview:**

I'm working on a microservices project using Spring Cloud Gateway.
To keep my configuration organized, I've split my route definitions into separate YAML files for each microservice.
These YAML files are imported in my application.yml using the spring.config.import property.

**Problem Description:**

When I access the /actuator/gateway/routes endpoint, I can see only the routes defined in the last imported YAML file. The routes from the other files are not visible.

**Example Implementation:**

Here's an example of my configuration:
application.yml

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - classpath:config/customer-management.yml
      - classpath:config/payment-instrument.yml
      - classpath:config/compliance.yml
      - classpath:config/switch-channel.yml
      - classpath:config/switch-operation.yml
      - classpath:config/switch-xpos.yml
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
  application:
    name: PwcApiGateway
  cloud:
    config:
      allow-override: false
    discovery:
      enabled: true
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
      enabled: true
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lower-case-service-id: true
          route-id-prefix: ""
    circuitbreaker:
      hystrix:
        enabled: true
```

customer-management.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        # ============ REST Routes ==========

        # CardFromInternalTokenCM
        - id: cardFromInternalTokenCMRest
          uri: ${PWC_CONNECT_API_CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE:https://127.0.0.1:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/customer-management/tokenization/card_from_internal_token
            - name: Dev
              args:
                enabled: ${GET_CARD_FROM_INTERNAL_TOKEN_ENABLED:false}
          metadata:
            fullResponseEncryption: false
            fullRequestDecryption: false
            fieldLevelResponseEncryption: false
            fieldLevelRequestDecryption: false

        # CardFromCMToken
        - id: cardFromTokenCMRest
          uri: ${PWC_CONNECT_API_CUSTOMER_MANAGEMENT_SERVICE:https://127.0.0.1:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/customer-management/v4.0/tokenization/card_from_token
          metadata:
            fullResponseEncryption: false
            fullRequestDecryption: false
            fieldLevelResponseEncryption: false
            fieldLevelRequestDecryption: false
```

payment-instrument.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        # ============ REST Routes ==========

        # PwcTokenVault
        - id: pwcTokenVaultPI
          uri: ${PWC_CONNECT_API_PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT_SERVICE:https://127.0.0.1:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path= /payment-instrument/v4.0/tokenization/card_from_token
          metadata:
            fullResponseEncryption: false
            fullRequestDecryption: false
            fieldLevelResponseEncryption: false
            fieldLevelRequestDecryption: false

        # updateCardEventNotification
        - id: updateCardEventNotification
          uri: ${PWC_CONNECT_API_PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT_SERVICE:https://127.0.0.1:8082}
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment-instrument/v4.0/cards/event_notification_list
          metadata:
            fullResponseEncryption: false
            fullRequestDecryption: false
            fieldLevelResponseEncryption: false
            fieldLevelRequestDecryption: false
```

... (similar YAML files for other microservices)

**Configuration:**

I have verified that each of my YAML files has the correct routes structure, and there are no typos in my configuration.
The application starts without errors.

**Question:**

What could be causing only the routes from the last imported YAML file to be visible in /actuator/gateway/routes? How can I make all routes from the imported files appear and merged correctly ?
Any insights, suggestions, or solutions are greatly appreciated.